# Auto refresh tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, refresh

When I upload image, it won't displays on the page until I go to eclipse -> right click on project -> "refresh (F5) "

How to refresh automatically after upload an image ?

Comment: Check the Workspace preference page for an option to do that automatically.